# Should I add memcached on my php app running apc

Tags: php, caching, memcached, fastcgi, apc

I have a php mysql application running on a single 32gb 12core server.
I already have APC Varnish installed, but I would like o try memcached + FastCgi aswell.

I've seen some people saying that running memcached together with APC is a bad idea, why?

since memcache is a memory object cache and APC is opcode cache I dont understand that.

Memcached should be good on my site since I have a lot of queries going on.

Also, on APC I have apc.shm_size set to 64M, maybe I should bring it up a bit consider I have a 32gb server.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks I read it, but it doesnt explain why having both sometimes is a bad idea

Comment: In that other question, I see lots of people saying “I use […] both”.